# ORA-31011: XML parsing failed, expected '<' instead of '?'

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xml-parsing

I'm trying to XML data from a file which contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BURS_REPORT>
   <REQUESTID>128546198</REQUESTID>
   <PARENT_REQUESTID>128546195</PARENT_REQUESTID>
   <REPORT_DESC>Description here</REPORT_DESC>
   <OUTPUT_FILE>path_here/o128546198.zip</OUTPUT_FILE>
   <DOCUMENT_STATUS>
      <KEY>1250168</KEY>
      <OUTPUT_TYPE>pdf</OUTPUT_TYPE>
      <DELIVERY>email</DELIVERY>
      <OUTPUT>path_here/1331000-1.pdf</OUTPUT>
      <STATUS>success</STATUS>
      <LOG />
   </DOCUMENT_STATUS>
</BURS_REPORT>
```

Code to retrieve content:

```
declare
  v_outfile_name varchar2(4500) := '/opt/apps/r12/d1ebs/conc/out/o128553806.out';
  t_temp varchar2(4500) := substr(v_outfile_name, instr(v_outfile_name, '/', -1) + 1);
  v_file bfile := bfilename('CONC_OUT', substr(v_outfile_name, instr(v_outfile_name, '/', -1) + 1));
  v_file_length number;
  v_buffer clob;
  v_xml xmltype;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('start');
  -- return
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_buffer, true);

  dbms_lob.fileopen(v_file, dbms_lob.file_readonly);
  v_file_length := dbms_lob.getlength(v_file);
  if v_file_length > 0 then
    dbms_lob.loadfromfile(v_buffer, v_file, v_file_length);
    v_xml := xmltype(v_buffer); -- error occurs here
  else
    v_xml := null;
  end if;
  dbms_lob.fileclose(v_file);
  dbms_lob.freetemporary(v_buffer);
  -- more code
end;
/
```

(Ed: taken from [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr1hB.png))

Running that gets:

```
Entered Exceptions with Others
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of '?'
Error at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272    
ORA-06512: at "APPS.NI_DOCUMENT_DISTRIBUTION_PUB", line 435
```

I tried to display the value of `v_temp`, and it shows strange characters:

```
v_temp: 㰿硭氠癥牳楯渽∱⸰∠敮捯摩湧㴢啔䘭㠢㼾਼䉕剓归䕐佒吾㱒䕑啅協䥄㸱㈸㔵㌷㔶㰯剅兕䕓呉䐾㱐䅒䕎呟剅兕䕓呉䐾ㄲ㠵㔳㜵〼⽐䅒䕎呟剅兕䕓呉䐾㱒䕐佒呟䑅千㹎䥁匠兵潴攠䕭慩氠䑩獴物扵瑩潮⁗潲步爼⽒䕐佒呟䑅千㸼何呐啔彆䥌䔾⽯灴⽡灰猯爱㈯搱敢猯捯湣⽯畴⽯ㄲ㠵㔳㜵㘮穩瀼⽏啔偕呟䙉䱅㸼䑏䍕䵅乔当呁呕匾㱋䕙㸱㈵㌱㜱㰯䭅夾㱏啔偕呟呙偅㹰摦㰯何呐啔彔奐䔾㱄䕌䥖䕒夾敭慩氼⽄䕌䥖䕒夾㱏啔偕吾⽯灴⽡灰猯爱㈯搱敢猯獨慲敳⽷敢影畯瑥猯义兵潴敟ㄳ〴㠶㤭ㄮ灤昼⽏啔偕吾㱓呁呕匾獵捣敳猼⽓呁呕匾㱌佇㸼⽌佇㸼⽄佃啍䕎呟協䅔啓㸼⽂啒卟剅偏剔
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your source file is encoded as UTF-8. The [documentation for `loadfromfile`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_lob.htm#ARPLS66733) says:

> If the character set is varying width, UTF-8 for example, the LOB value is stored in the fixed-width UCS2 format. Therefore, if you are using DBMS_LOB.LOADFROMFILE, the data in the BFILE should be in the UCS2 character set instead of the UTF-8 character set.

If you use [`loadclobfromfile`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_lob.htm#ARPLS66728) instead then it can handle the UTF-8 source file, you just have to pass a few more arguments:

```
declare
  v_outfile_name varchar2(4500) := '/opt/apps/r12/d1ebs/conc/out/o128553806.out';
  v_file bfile := bfilename('CONC_OUT', substr(v_outfile_name, instr(v_outfile_name, '/', -1) + 1));
  v_file_length number;
  v_buffer clob;
  v_xml xmltype;
  v_dest_offset integer := 1;
  v_src_offset integer := 1;
  v_bfile_csid number := 0;
  v_lang_context integer := 0;
  v_warning integer;
begin
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_buffer, true);
  dbms_lob.fileopen(v_file, dbms_lob.file_readonly);
  v_file_length := dbms_lob.getlength(v_file);
  if v_file_length > 0 then
    dbms_lob.loadclobfromfile(dest_lob => v_buffer,
      src_bfile => v_file,
      amount => v_file_length,
      dest_offset => v_dest_offset,
      src_offset => v_src_offset,
      bfile_csid => v_bfile_csid,
      lang_context => v_lang_context,
      warning => v_warning);
    v_xml := xmltype(v_buffer);
  end if;
  dbms_lob.fileclose(v_file);
  dbms_lob.freetemporary(v_buffer);
end;
/
```

I've defaulted the CSID and ignored the values set in the OUT parameters for brevity.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your feedback.